gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libopenh264.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
When trying to use gazebo on ubuntu 20.04 with ros-noetic I got the error
gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libopenh264.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance.
I tried to simply run
gazebo

when running the command
apt search libopenh264

I get
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done



Is libopenh264 installed?
You can check is via apt search libopenh.

Thanks for the reply.
I added the results in the question

You should have something like that: libopenh264-6/jammy,now 2.2.0+dfsg-2 amd64 [installed] (I'm on ubuntu 22 so it's slightly different).
Type apt search libopenh264 (the missing library) and install it if it's not.

When running apt search libopenh264 I get Sorting... Done Full Text Search... Done  What can I do when the library is not found?

Even after a sudo apt update?

Yes... There might be something wrong with my ubuntu installation. i got gazebo to work by installing openh264 from source. Much thanks for your help though.

I fixed this issue by building openh264 from the source. I chose the version v2.0.0 which creates the libopenh264.so.5 shared object file. Newer versions created objects like libopenh264.so.7 and didn't work.
git clone -b v2.0.0 https://github.com/cisco/openh264
cd openh264
make -j4
sudo make install
ls /usr/local/lib
# libopenh264.so.5 ........
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
ls ${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}
#openh264.pc


wget http://ciscobinary.openh264.org/libopenh264-1.8.0-linux64.4.so.bz2

bunzip2 libopenh264-1.8.0-linux64.4.so.bz2

sudo mv libopenh264-1.8.0-linux64.4.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenh264.so.5

sudo ldconfig


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
